# Read size of linux disk with python

Tags: python

I'm not worried about portability at the moment, I am just wanting to read the size of say, `/dev/sdb` in bytes.

I tried `os.path.getsize('/dev/sdb/')` but it returned 0.

I also tried to do `open('/dev/sdb/', 'rb')` and `read()` and `tell()` to get the count, but that is way too slow.

Comment: Use `sysfs`.  Read `/sys/block/sdb/size`, e.g.

Comment: @BrianCain You should make that an answer. It's short, but right.

Comment: @Carsten I agree, I'll post an answer right now because I have some working python code to go with it, but I'll upvote/accept Brian's if they would like points :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `sysfs`. Read `/sys/block/sdb/size` like so:

```
BLOCK_SIZE_BYTES = 512 # usually?  always?  *shrug*

def get_disk_size(blockdev):
    blocks = int(open('/sys/block/{blockdev}/size'.format(**locals())).read())
    return blocks * BLOCK_SIZE_BYTES
```

Comment: You can figure out the physical block (sector) size from sysfs in Ubuntu at least by reading `/sys/block/<disk>/queue/physical_block_size` (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-block).